# Electric fields (a-level) question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields

A proton is accelerated from rest by a uniform electric field, strength is 2x10^5.
calculate the time it takes to travel 0.05 m.

I calculated force to be 3.2x10^-14.  I then found wk done is, wk = force x distance = 1.6x10^15.
Next, I used this is equal to 1/2 mv^2. Hence v = 1.91...x10^12.
Then I used t= d/s
Which gave me 3.62x10^-8.

But the answer is 7.3x10^-8. Why can't I do the question this way instead of using f = ma. Why is this wrong?

Comment: What are your units? Velocity cannot be more that 3E8 m/s...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using equations for a particle which is moving with constant velocity but this is a acclerated particle and you need to use equation like S= $ut+1/2at^{2}$ and solve a quadratic to get time.

You can't simply use the basic ones because the velocity is changing with time, It will gradually increase to maximum value and you need to take that in mind.
You are just using the maximum velocity that is why time taken is very less.
You just need to revisit your kinematics notes.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense to me now.